# Error in "System > Configuration" Admin Page on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, fatal-error, locale

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Locale::getAlias() in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php on line 243

This error appears when I try to open the tab System > Configuration but also appears on the dashboard.

I have looked at the code but doesn't have any idea of whats going on. Maybe a Location / Time Zone error.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [static call to Zend_Locale::getAlias()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php#L243). The messsage actually means that the class `Zend_Locale` wasn't found. Make sure, your Magento installation is complete, especially that the file `lib/Zend/Locale.php` exists and is readable by PHP.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are missing a file. If you FTP'ed the files to your server, it may have failed during transfer.